# How to apply an SMT to a single topic in Kafka connect?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I would like to apply a set of SMT (Single Message Transforms) to one single topic.

I have the following configuration..

```
connector.class: io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
name: test
database.server.name: testserver
database.hostname: 127.0.0.1
database.port: 5432
database.dbname: test
database.user: testuser
database.password: "testpass"
schema.whitelist: test

table.whitelist: test.topic1, test.topic2, test.topic3

transforms:unwrap,extractTopic1Key,extractTopic1Value,extractTopic2Key


transforms.unwrap.type: io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope
transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode: rewrite
transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones: false

transforms.extractTopic1Key.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractTopic1Value.type: org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Value

transforms.extractTopic1Key.field: propname
transforms.extractTopic1Value.field: propvalue

transforms.extractTopic1Key.predicate: test_topic1
transforms.extractTopic1Value.predicate: test_topic1

transforms.extractTopic2Key.type:org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key
transforms.extractTopic2Key.field: id
transforms.extractTopic2Key.predicate: test_topic2


predicates=test_topic1,test_topic2
predicates.test_topic1.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.predicates.TopicNameMatches
predicates.test_topic1.pattern=.*topic1

predicates.test_topic2.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.predicates.TopicNameMatches
predicates.test_topic2.pattern=.*topic2

key.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable: false
value.converter: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable: false
decimal.handling.mode: string
include.schema.changes: false
#Adds header which says insert,update,delete
transforms.unwrap.operation.header: true
snapshot.mode: initial
heartbeat.interval.ms: 10000
slot.name: test
```

I am getting the following error..

```java
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.apply(TransformationChain.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.sendRecords(WorkerSourceTask.java:308)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:234)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField.apply(ExtractField.java:61)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain.lambda$apply$0(TransformationChain.java:50)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
        ... 11 more
```

When I remove the all transformations except `unwrap`, it is working fine.
My sample topic data looks as follows.

**Key**

```json
{"propname":"my.test.prop"}
```

**Value**

```json
{"propname":"my.test.prop","propvalue":"10","__deleted":"false"}
```

`propname` is the primary key in the table.

What is wrong with the above configuration and how do we apply specific SMTs only to specified topics?

P.S: I am using Confluent Platform 5.3.1

Answer (score 3):

[apache-kafka](/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) has included supporting for conditionally applying an SMT since 2.6.0 version through [**KIP-585** - Filter and Conditional SMTs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-585%3A+Filter+and+Conditional+SMTs).

You are using Confluent Platform 5.3.1. [5.3.1](https://docs.confluent.io/5.3.1/release-notes/index.html#cp-5-3-1-release-notes) is a bugfix release of Confluent Platform that provides you with Apache Kafka 2.3.0, the latest stable version of Kafka.

So you need to upgrade Kafka Connect to 2.6.0 version.

Comment: I remember to have done with some configuration, but I have not saved my code. Can we use the 2.6.0 jar in the classpath of the connector to work with latest SMTs?